# ImageField returning null when there is a value in the database: Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to retrieve values from my database, but I am not getting the response I am looking for. My question is  how do I get the value that is under `Image` in my database entry?

Database entry:

```
ID  name        image
-----------------------------
11  "example"   "myimager.jpg"
```

When I retrieve a list, I get this response for this entry:

```
{ "image": null, "name": "example" }
```

Model:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

View:

```
class GetImageViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This ViewSet automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = Images.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Serializer:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ['image', 'name']
```

Comment: Does the file exist in you [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT)?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I am using django-tenants and django-storage[google]. So would a setting there be causing an issue?

Comment: Have you run migrations for your app? Also, I see `url` in your serializer, but where is it defined in your model? In your templates you can do image.image.url, but the serializer should just use the attribute name, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you request the model instance and the field is not None, then you may need to declare the field explicitly using [DRF ImageField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield). Otherwise you're going to have to dig into `django.db.fields.file.FileDescriptor` why `__get__` decides to return None. It's not obvious to me why it would.

Comment: @Leo: Yes, I have run migrations. Sorry, 'url' was there from one of the ways I was trying to get access to it, but it shouldn't be there now. I have removed it. I am not using the template. I am accessing it through DRF. So I am using a get request to retrieve it.